# Cordova Android build process fails when adding splash screens in config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I added Splash screen plugin to my Cordova project and added all the required splash screen references in my config.xml file. But when I am now trying to build my android app, it fails with error:

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\wamp\www\my_cordova_app\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml:36: AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

when I am removing all splash screen references:

........

in config file, it rebuilds successfully, but there are no splash screens in mobile app.

Comment: Have you add `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />` and `<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="3000" />` these two attribute in config.xml file?

Comment: Yes, those are there